# Why do people declare both an interface and a class?

Tags: typescript

At my workplace, I see a lot of files that look like this:

```
export interface IExample {
  a: number
}

export class Example implements IExample {
  a: number = 2
}
```

Why would one do this? Are there any advantages to it?

For me, it's just duplication, most of the classes declared this way are out-of-sync with their interfaces.

Comment: Depends. Perhaps people are trying to adhere to the [SOLID principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID). Given that you see that at your workplace, why not ask your colleagues?

Comment: @Carcigenicate but these classes are unique and in all of the cases the interface is just a copy, not something that can be implemented by other classes

Comment: That's true, but the interface might later have fewer methods than the class, in which case they won't be structurally the same type. Having the interface separately makes the code easier to refactor later.

Comment: @VLAZ How would that help with SOLID? I asked around but everyone just dismissed me with "it's how it's done around here"

Comment: @kaya3 How exactly does that make it simpler to refactor? It seems to me that it just creates confusing errors that are caused by those two entities being out-of-sync.

Comment: @ŁukaszKarczewski it's the L and D in SOLID are all about using interfaces.

Comment: An interface is about a shape and a class is about a content with some shape (its own or with some restrictions given from an interface).

Comment: Suppose some code does call a function accepting IFoo with something that is not an instance of Foo. Since the function only depends on the methods declared in the interface, this is fine. Now suppose Foo needs to be refactored to have another method which is unrelated to what that function does: if the function's parameter type were Foo then the code calling it with something else would break, but because IFoo remains unchanged then this problem doesn't occur. The extra method added to Foo might get declared on a different interface.

Comment: @kaya3 thanks, I get it. But what with classes and their instances for which it is impossible to call such a function with their "equivalent"? The classes I see are pretty unique, not really meant to be replaced by something else in a function call. I guess in such a situation this separation is pointless?

Comment: They might still be called with mock objects in unit tests, for example.